# Sage Math elliptic curve with singularity points

Tags: math, plot, curve, sage, elliptic-curve

I am new in sage and I have a problem. I am trying to plot the curve `f(x,y)=y^2 - x^2*(x+3)`, but it never works. Can somebody help ?

I tried this:

```
sage: E = EllipticCurve([0,3,0,0,0]);
sage: E;
```

and it gives the error `ArithmeticError: invariants (0, 3, 0, 0, 0) define a singular curve`.

Comment: Are you getting an error message or unexpected behaviour?  Update your question with why it "never works"

Comment: i tried this:
`sage: E = EllipticCurve([0,3,0,0,0]);
sage: E;`
and it gives the error `ArithmeticError: invariants (0, 3, 0, 0, 0) define a singular curve`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do an implicit plot.

```
f(x,y)=y^2 - x^2*(x+3)
implicit_plot(f,(x,-3,3),(y,-3,3))
```

[Looks singular to me](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?q=jjxurf)!  That would explain your error, probably `EllipticCurve` only will work with nonsingular curves.